# Postman: How to Export/Download API Documentation from Postman?

Tags: postman

I have created a collection in Postman to have a bunch of API endpoints. I can add team members to my Postman workspace and share documentation links publicly online. **I was looking for a download link so I could download the API documentation as an HTML site inside a folder and add it to my project.**

Is there anything like that at Postman?

Answer (score 23):

You can export the collection as a json as shown in the other answer and then run a tool to convert it into an HTML document that you can host wherever you want.

I created a simple python executable to do just that -
https://github.com/karthiks3000/postman-doc-gen

Comment: Wow! That's great!!

Comment: Great! Perfect Script!

Comment: @SiddiquiNoor Please accept the answer if it works for you. It will help other members to find the relevent answer quickly.

Comment: @ManonandanSK, yes the solution given by Karthiks3000 worked somehow but it is still not yet added as a service in Postman. I upvoted the answer and still waiting to have any automated feature in Postman.

Comment: How shoould we get the json from the postman doc page? it's not "shown in the other answer" as you said

Answer (score 6):

Hi @Siddiqui currently this feature is not available, I do it by going to my collection documentation and getting it to print when the print prompt is shown I save the document as PDF before finalizing the print options. Once I get it in PDF I have all sorts options to do as I want. This is the closest I have been to downloading my collection documentation. 
[image: I am adding a screenshot to visually show what I mean.]

I have redacted information for privacy.
Hope this helps or leave a comment if I can be of any further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Postman generated API documentation is meant to be shared and consumed via workspace and URL to help ensure it is kept up to date and does not go stagnant. Because documentation will most likely be regularly updated with examples, new endpoints, and other elements anything downloaded will quickly be out of date. I know that a PDF generated version has been discussed as part of future releases, but keeping API documentation up to date is the priority.

Comment: I think this is a much needed feature as most of the times, the people who need to give the approval for API, will not look into  a URL which is shared to them and most of of the Enterprise type discussions will either by Email or by Confluence. As of now there is no way to extract the documentation as a PDF file and send it as an attachment.

Comment: i understand the importance of keeping everything up to date, but forcing it to be kept inside the Postman environment is just project mgmt with extra step.

Comment: One person's terrorist is another person's frredom fighter. One person's "help ensure it is kept up to date and does not go stagnant" is another person's "make sure you are locked to our (Postman's) subscription plan. Recently Postman had a big downtime and in myu company we got locked out of documentation and workspace. I would trade Postman for OpenAPI in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question as @S.Serpooshan on how to export the documentation JSON and it was not immediately obvious. So I thought it'd be useful to include it here, to supplement @karthiks3000's answer.

From either the webpage or desktop app, from the collections view, click on the 3 dots (...) to the right of your collection, then select Export:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this is to print the page to PDF from the web browser. It's not perfect but it is usable.

Answer (score 0):

https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-data/
to export the doc to json
and then run the script by @karthiks3000 (https://github.com/karthiks3000/postman-doc-gen)

Comment: This answer already has given by @karthiks3000 but I was looking for a solution inside Postman.